# (SOLVED) add external link in custom magento plugin

Tags: magento2

I'm updating a Magento plugin and I'd like to add an external link like this:

```
<a href="myweblink" target "_blank">My weblink </a>
```

I tried to do it adding these lines in layout.xml file (that is the model I use)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="footer_blog_link" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Condizioni di contratto e termini di utilizzo</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">https://www.fattura24.com/termini-utilizzo/</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
        </arguments>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Regolamento integrarivo (delle Condizioni di Contratto) per l'UTENTE che utilizza moduli per E-Commerce di Fattura24</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">https://www.fattura24.com/regolamento-ecommerce/</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
        </arguments>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Privacy</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">https://www.fattura24.com/policy/</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I'm not displaying the links in admin footer of my extension.

I put this file in /adminhtml/layout
then I updated the app, flushed magento cache, reindexed but still can't display links

Comment: Why `system.xml` ? you could not add this in `system.xml` and the error confirm that. Do it instead in layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solved in this way: I edited system.xml adding code like this:

```
<field id="info_link" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                         <frontend_model>Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Block\System\Config\InfoLink</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Then I created an InfoLink.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Block\System\Config;

class InfoLink extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $_template = 'Fattura24_AppFatturazione::system/config/infoLink.phtml';

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope label
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    /**
     * Return element html
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
```

Eventually I added the template named infoLink.phtml:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"https://www.fattura24.com/termini-utilizzo/\" target=\"_blank\">Condizioni di contratto e termini di utilizzo di Fattura24</a>" . "<br />";
      echo "<a href=\"https://www.fattura24.com/regolamento-ecommerce/\" target=\"_blank\">Regolamento F24 integrativo (delle Condizioni di Contratto) per modulo Magento </a>" . "<br />";
      echo "<a href=\"https://www.fattura24.com/policy/\" target=\"_blank\">Privacy di Fattura24</a>" . "<br />";
?>
```

That is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add that in admin area:

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/your_layout_name.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="footer_blog_link" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Condizioni di contratto e termini di utilizzo</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">https://www.fattura24.com/termini-utilizzo/</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
        </arguments>
        ...
```

Comment: I added the code you suggested, then I updated my app and flush magento cache, and reindex, but I can't display the link in admin

Comment: The footer of admin Magento or if your admin footer extension ?

Comment: the admin footer of my extension

Comment: ok, can you share me the layout extension content ?

Comment: updated question :-) Thanks

Comment: The original one, not that you updated, `view/adminhtml/layout/?` how many files contain the layout folder ?

Comment: I added layout folder since in /adminhtml I have got only system.xml file

Comment: It doesn't work like this, you have to find first the name of footer container if it has been added via xml otherwise you have to add it in the bottom of the container page

Comment: I have to add it, and I think I should also add the container page, since I have got only system.xml file in /adminhtml

Comment: ok, try that...